# input array values sum using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have input fields like this

```
<input  name="unittotal[]" type="text" id="unittotal[]" onchange="sumofunittotal();" size="3"  />
<input  name="unittotal[]" type="text" id="unittotal[]"  onchange="sumofunittotal();"  size="3"  />
<input  name="unittotal[]" type="text" id="unittotal[]"   onchange="sumofunittotal();" size="3"  />
<input  name="unittotal[]" type="text" id="unittotal[]"   onchange="sumofunittotal();"  size="3"  />
```

.
.
.

```
<input name="total" type="text" id="total" value="">
```

if i enter value in unittotal field onchange the final text box value is should be sum of that unit total using javascript.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: (Not question related) Your inputs have the same ID. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really

Comment: if i enter number in unittotal text box. i want sum of value in that total input text box

Comment: All those input are precisely the same. Javascript won't be able to distinguish one from the other without some hacky trickery.

Comment: If you want the sum, then write yourself a little code that'll give you the sum.

Comment: please do a bit more research on the internet(like w3cschools.com) about accessing values, and just to mention the id attribute should be unique in the markup

Comment: function sumofunittotal()
{    
    var items = document.getElementsById("unittotal[]");
    var itemCount = items.length;
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
    {
        total = total +  parseInt(items[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('total').value = total;

Comment: like this i tried but its not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Here's the working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/jxJg7/) for you.

You need not use duplicate id values for your HTML elements. Consider using class name instead. Refer the markup and the code that calculates the total. I hope its self-explanatory enough.

**JavaScript:**

```
function updateTotal() {
    var total = 0;//
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("input");
    var values = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
        values.push(parseFloat(list[i].value));
    }
    total = values.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array){
        return previousValue + currentValue;
    });
    document.getElementById("total").value = total;    
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text"  class='input' value="0" onchange='updateTotal();'>
<input type="text"  class='input' value="0" onchange='updateTotal();'>
<input type="text"  class='input' value="0" onchange='updateTotal();'>
<input type="text"  class='input' value="0" onchange='updateTotal();'>

<input name="total" type="text" id="total" value="">
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
<input type="text" size="3" class="add" />
<input type="text" size="3" class="add" />
<input type="text" size="3" class="add" />
<input type="text" size="3" class="add" />
<hr>
<input type="text" size="3" id="sum" />
```

and the javascript:

```
(function () {

    var elms = document.querySelectorAll('.add'),
        arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(elms),
        onChange = function () {
            var result = 0;
            arr.forEach(function (el) {
                result = result + +el.value;
            });

            document.getElementById('sum').value = result;
        };

    arr.forEach(function (el) {
        el.addEventListener('change', onChange);
    });

}());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/65b6T/

Answer (score 1):

try this , and see in detail in fiddle [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/69Xcd/6/).
HTML

```
<table width="300px" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;background-color:#E8DCFF">
    <tr>
        <td width="40px">1</td>
        <td>
            <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>
            <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>
            <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>
            <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>
            <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>
            <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="summation">

        <td align="left">Total :</td>
        <td align="left"><span id="sum">0</span>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
     //handler to trigger sum event
     $(".txt").each(function () {

         $(this).keyup(function () {
             calculateSum();
         });
     });

 });

 function calculateSum() {

     var sum = 0;
     //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
     $(".txt").each(function () {

         //add only if the value is number
         if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
             sum += parseFloat(this.value);
         }

     });
     //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
     $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a DEMO for this solution. http://jsfiddle.net/jxJg7/1/
NOTES:
It works only if your values are integers.
I created a function that will force the user to put numbers only on the inputs
Make sure you remove the duplicated IDs

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sumofunittotal() {
    var total = 0;
    var cusid_ele = document.getElementsByClassName('inputtosum');
    for (var i = 0; i < cusid_ele.length; ++i) {
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(cusid_ele[i].value)) )
    total += parseInt(cusid_ele[i].value);  
    }
    document.getElementById('total').value=total;
}

function onlynumber(e) {
    if (e.shiftKey === true ) {
    if (e.which == 9) {
    return true;
    }
    return false;
    }
    if (e.which > 57) {
    return false;
    }
    if (e.which==32) {
    return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>

<input  name="unittotal[]" class="inputtosum" type="text" onchange="sumofunittotal();" onkeydown="return onlynumber(event);" size="3"  />
<input  name="unittotal[]" class="inputtosum" type="text" onchange="sumofunittotal();" onkeydown="return onlynumber(event);" size="3"  />
<input  name="unittotal[]" class="inputtosum" type="text" onchange="sumofunittotal();" onkeydown="return onlynumber(event);" size="3"  />
<input  name="unittotal[]" class="inputtosum" type="text" onchange="sumofunittotal();" onkeydown="return onlynumber(event);" size="3"  />
<input name="total" type="text" id="total" value="">
```